# Having fill error with connection

Tags: c#

I really tried a lot to know where is the mistake into this below code that showing to me the error message:

> " fill: selectcommand.connection property has not been initialized "

[click to see the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMpsO.jpg)
 but i couldnt really get the mistake into code below please could you help me to fix this code and avoid this error message

```
protected void addadsbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("Location");
        string Location = string.Empty;

        var user = Session["UsrNme"];
        Location = cookie.Value;

        string FileExtentio = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg1.FileName);
        string FileExtentio2 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUploadImg2.FileName);

        string makervalue = string.Empty;

        string Gearvalue = string.Empty;

        string NyAdsDesc = TextBox2.Text;

        SqlConnection addadscon = new SqlConnection(sc);

        var UsrNme = Session["UsrNme"];



        if (Session["UsrNme"] != null && cookie != null)
        {

            }


            if (FileUploadImg1.HasFile || FileUploadImg2.HasFile || FileUploadImg3.HasFile || FileUploadImg4.HasFile || FileUploadImg5.HasFile)
            {

                var filess = new[] { FileExtentio, FileExtentio2, FileExtentio3, FileExtentio4, FileExtentio5 };
                filess = filess.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
                var extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".png" };
                if ((filess.Except(extensions).Count()) <= 0)
                {

                    if (DropDownList3.SelectedValue == "no")
                    {
                        AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                        adsstutslbel.Text = "- Please select ads status";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }


                    if (DropDownList2.SelectedValue == "no")
                    {
                        AdsWrngPanel.Visible = true;
                        adscondlbel.Text = "- Please select ads condition";
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }



                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [ads] ([Section], [Category], [UID], [AdsTit], [AdsDesc], [Country], [State],[AdsDate],
        [City], [AdsPrice], [Img1], [img2], [img3], [img4],[img5], [Wtags], [Address],[Condition], [Status],[Maker],[Year],[Gear],[RoomNo],
        [Space],[Shower],[Garage],[Currency])
        VALUES (@Section, @Category, @UID, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Img1, @img2, @img3,
        @img4, @img5, @Wtags, @Address,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage,@Currency)", addadscon);


                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Secdrdoads.SelectedItem.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maker", makervalue);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", Yearvalue);

                    string imgnouser = "/images/general/nouser.jpg";

                    if (FileUploadImg1.HasFile)
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", FileUploadImg1.FileName);
                        FileUploadImg1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/images/AdsImgs/" + FileUploadImg1.FileName));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Img1", imgnouser);
                    }


                    addadscon.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    addadscon.Close();

                }

                else
                {
                    AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.Text = "Error: The file should have .png or .jpg format only";
                    AddNwAddsWrngFrmtLbl.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;


                }



            }

            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO [ads] ([Section], [Category], [UID], [AdsTit], [AdsDesc], [Country], [State],[AdsDate],
        [City], [AdsPrice], [Wtags], [Address],[Condition], [Status],[Maker],[Year],[Gear],[RoomNo], [Space],[Shower],[Garage])
        VALUES (@Section, @Category, @UID, @AdsTit, @AdsDesc, @Country, @State,@adsDate, @City, @AdsPrice, @Wtags, @Address,@Condition, @Status,@Maker,@Year,@Gear,@RoomNo,@Space,@Shower,@Garage)", addadscon);


                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Wtags", addadswtagtxtbtn.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Condition", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adsDate", DateTime.Now);


                addadscon.Open();
                cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
                addadscon.Close();

            }


            MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 3;
            ViwMyAdsPanel.Visible = true;

            CheckUsrAds();


        }


    }
```

Comment: You need to tell the command object which connection to use. Try this: `cmd.Connection = addadscon;`

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It has been told as a second parameter on `new SqlCommand(...` part actually.

Comment: On which line you get this error exactly? I feel like you don't show the relevant code to us since there is no "selectcommand" part in your code.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, but I also see something else, the error message says "selectcommand", and the subject says "Fill", so this is probably an error related to a dataset/datatable, but there is no code related to that in the question.

Comment: the exception is obviously not happening in this block of code. Do you have any data adapter.fill anywhere in the rest of your code or a data bound control on your page?

Comment: Hi all dear @Soner Gönül i cant know in which line exactly as the web application is already uploaded to godaddy server

Comment: Dear @LasseV.Karlsen V. Karlsen i have tried what you mention before but the problem still remain

Comment: Yes, you're right because that is not the problem. I was too quick to comment and didn't notice the additional parameter. Do you have any code in your application that fills a dataset or a datatable? Also, you should definitely add some logging or whatnot so that you can pinpoint errors in production. How did you get the error message at all if you don't have logging?

Comment: Hi @Lasse V. Karlsen as i mention the website is has been uploaded to Server and it was working fine on my laptop and it has similar code for other parts in my web application if you can you can go to www.berava.com and register as new user and then try to add an ads then you will find this error

Comment: @Znar If you can see the 'Yellow Page' errors on web page, you can check which line is causing this issue that would be highlighted in red color or post a screen shot of it. Don't forget to mask any sensitive information in the screenshot !!

Comment: Also what is the value of `sc`, in the line: 
`SqlConnection addadscon = new SqlConnection(sc);` ? 
Are you sure this is not empty string in your production server?

Comment: Hi @SivaGopal please could you check my post i have added new image of the error just click on " click to see the error image "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to the comments and based on the exception screenshot you posted, I think the problem is stemming from the following event:

`beravoSV.User_panel.adNewdadsbtn_Click(...)`

So inside this event(including methods called from this event) check for `DataAdapter` related code. For e.g:

`SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, connection);`

and make sure a proper `connection` is getting passed to the dataadapter instance.

I think that should fix the issue.